# Как обратить к параметру max в теге input в js?

Tags: javascript

Нужно обратиться к параметру max тега input, для динамического изменения.
Но не знаю как обратиться к нему, так же как и с value не выходит

Пусть будет такая ситуация, например:

`<input type="number" id="x" max="">`

Как мне обратиться к параметру max?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взять значение из атрибута можно с помощью соответствующе названного метода: **[getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**

```
document.getElementById('x').getAttribute('max')
```

Установить значение через **[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)**

---

Но вообще и простое обращение

```
document.getElementById('x').max
```

тоже должно работать